# Play framework - Scala, Method is defined twice

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I want to map multiple URLs into an overloaded controller method as below. But I get the error  "Method account is defined twice". So, is it possible to do this in scala - play framework?

```
GET     /order/:userId             controllers.Application.account(userId)       
GET     /order/:userId/:date       controllers.Application.account(userId, date)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because of the way the reverse routing works, you need to specify both parameters to use `account` like that. Here's an example that works:

In Application.scala:

```
def account(userId: String, date: String) = Action {
  Ok(userId + " and " + date)
}
```

In routes:

```
GET /order/:userId           controllers.Application.account(userId, date="")
GET /order/:userId/:date     controllers.Application.account(userId, date)
```